Tikz path picture with relative positioning not centered
I'm trying to center an image inside a tikz circle. Using path picture this is very easy. But when the position of the node is defined via above right=-1cm and -1cm of, the image is not centered anymore:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[
                circle, 
                color=white, 
                fill=blue, 
                minimum size=5cm,
            ] (circle1) at ([xshift=0.3\paperheight, yshift=0.65\paperheight]current page.south west) {circle 1};
            
            \node[
            circle, 
            color=white, 
            fill=gray, 
            above right=-1cm and -1cm of circle1, 
            minimum size=3cm,
            path picture={
                \node at (path picture bounding box.south west){
                    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
                };
            },
            ]
            (circle2) {circle 2};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}



If you're using current page you will need remember picture. Anyway, above right sets anchor=south west and your node inside path picture inherits that (but then you reference the south west corner of the pth picture bounding box anyway). I'd suggest \node[anchor=center] at (path picture bounding box.center) {…};.

The answer of @Qrrbrbirlbel works and anchor=center is the way to go. Below you find the working solution:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[
                circle, 
                color=white, 
                fill=blue, 
                minimum size=5cm,
            ] (circle1) at ([xshift=0.3\paperheight, yshift=0.65\paperheight]current page.south west) {circle 1};
            
            \node[
                circle, 
                color=white, 
                fill=gray, 
                above right=-1cm and -1cm of circle1, 
                minimum size=3cm,
                path picture={
                    \node[anchor=center] at (path picture bounding box.center){
                        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
                    };
                },
            ]
            (circle2) {circle 2};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}


